# Trace with Boson operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, bosons

I want to compute the following trace
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\exp(-\sum_k\varepsilon_k a_k^\dagger a_k)a_i a_j)
$$
with bosonic operators $a_i,a_j$. I think the result will be proportional to $\delta_{i,j}$ but I have no idea how to do this precisely. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the trace, the operator $\exp(-\sum_k\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k)$ is diagonal while for, any state $|n\rangle$, $\langle n|a^2|n\rangle=0$, so that sums up to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But wouldn't this imply that correlations of the form $\langle a_i a_j\rangle$ always vanish and we are back in the fermionic regime?

Comment: Not exactly. What determines being bosons or fermions is the positivity of the energy and so, the way $a^\dagger,\ a$ commutes or anti-commutes each other.